# How to compute count rule in python dataframe? (Similar to count if in SQL)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

My goal is to calculate the amount of purchases made by costumers before the current date.

Ex:

```
ID         Date           Purchases_Made      Purchase_Mades_So_Far(Result)    
ClientA    Jan/2019       5                   5
ClientA    Feb/2019       8                   13   
ClientB    Jan/2019       1                   1
ClientB    Feb/2019       3                   4
```

I have tried lambda expressions and group by but none of them worked.

My best try so far is:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
      for index2, compare in df.iterrows():
        row['Result'] = teste[(compare['ID'] == row['ID']) &
                              (compare['Date'] < row['Date'])                    
                             ]['Purchases_Made'].sum()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby('ID')['Purchases_Made'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        ID      Date  Purchases_Made  Purchase_Mades_So_Far(Result)  Result
0  ClientA  Jan/2019               5                              5       5
1  ClientA  Feb/2019               8                             13      13
2  ClientB  Jan/2019               1                              1       1
3  ClientB  Feb/2019               3                              4       4
```